# Require Github PR approvals from multiple groups

Tags: github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I'm using the [codeowners](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) file to [require PR approvals](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-a-branch-protection-rule#creating-a-branch-protection-rule) before they can be merged. What I'd like to do is:

1. Require all PRs to have at least one approval from a group of code owners (engineers)
2. Require all PRs to have at least one approval from a group of QA

It seems like the code owners file does a hierarchical thing where only one group owns the code and you can create rules for certain directories but those will just override the default code owner.

My current `.github/CODEOWNERS` file looks like this:

```
* @my-org/engineer-code-owners
```

Is there a way to require at least one approval from two different groups?

Answer (score 13):

You can list multiple users/groups on a single line (separated by a single space) to request multiple reviews.

```
* @my-org/engineer-code-owners @my-org/qa-code-owners
```

As of time of writing, there’s no way to require a review from all code owners assigned to a pull request.

> Is there any way to require all of the listed people to approve?

> No, there currently isn’t a way to do that built-in to the CODEOWNERS feature.

See [CODEOWNERS reference](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners#codeowners-syntax) and [thread](https://github.community/t/codeowner-required-reviews/356/9) on required reviews.

Comment: And would this allow me to require at least one review from _each_ group?

Comment: @brady-dowling unfortunately no. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: grrrrr - I wanted that too!!!

Answer (score 4):

On one line of CODEOWNERS, you can *request reviews* from multiple reviewers  but you can't *require approvals*.

In the repo settings, branch protection, you can require a certain *number* of approvals but you can't specify *who*.

I was really hoping I could stop myself merging without QA approval!